# Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException was thrown when try to open Tabbar.xml

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio

First of all I am very noob at this, so please consider that when giving me a solution.
I implemented an Android app which scan a barcode using ZXing.Mobile.Form. So far the app looks like it is working, but when I try to edit the Tabbar.xml file, I get an error message which says "Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException". Can someone please help me which this issue. I attached a screenshot to better see the issue.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMLqT.png)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0dkC.png)

Comment: Please include the stack trace as code and not as an image. Can you elaborate more and what it means when you say "when I try to edit the Tabbar.xml file?" What are you trying to do and why?

Comment: I updated the picture. By editing the Tabbar.xml I mean I want to add buttons and text, but I am unable to do that because the Tabbar.xml file has an error.

Comment: @tomerpacific ^

Comment: I have posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshots you have provided, the error you have is because you have to set your application theme to be Theme.AppCompact.

You will need to add `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` to your manifest.